# WorkflowTemplates doesn't show App Workflows

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I'm using the [WorkflowTemplates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.workflowtemplates.aspx) property on the ClientContext.Web to try and locate a Workflow that has been installed by my App. Basically I want to be able to attach my Workflow to ListItem actions programmatically when the app is installed.

I'm managing to do this with Remote Event Receivers, but I'm not able to locate my Workflows to do the same thing.

The property returns the 2 workflows that are built in to Sharepoint (Disposition Approval and Three-state).

Comment: I'm beginning to think this isn't possible. It looks like my problem stems from the workflow being installed in the App Web and the List that I want to attach it to being in the Host Web